# Insert into table but avoid duplicates for multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to insert into table if table does not already contain those values.

This is my table

ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4

My table contains the following data:

0 | "a1" | "a2" | "a3" | "a4" |

1 | "b1" | "b2" | "b3" | "b4" |

2 | "c1" | "c2" | "c3" | "c4" |

I would like to not allow insert of the following input:

3 | "b1" | "b2" | "b3" | "d4" |

But allow the following:

3 | "a1" | "b2" | "c3" | "d4" |

I have tried the following

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) SELECT * FROM (SELECT :val1, :val2, :val3, :val4) as tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE Col1=:val1 AND Col2=:val2 AND Col3=:Val3)
```

This works fine unless :val1==:val2.

Is there a better way to insert and avoid duplicates?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by a duplicate here. Is it a duplicate if the values are in any order in col1,2,3,4? for example is it a duplicate if you already have 5,6,7,8 and you present 8,5,7,6?

Comment: That would not be a duplicate. A duplicate would be if and only if all columns have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

you can create `unique constraint/primary key` by combining `(Col1, Col2, Col3)` to insert unique records.

Comment: This does sound like a good solution but I would like to avoid creating another column.

Comment: You don't need to create a new column, you need to just create an unique constraint on these three columns.

Comment: @SJN please add example as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

> INSERT IGNORE

so it will ignore records that already exist in the table.

> REPLACE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html

to replace the existing record

Comment: Insert ignore only ignores errors. That is not what i am looking for.